# How to manage photo tagging on a modal dialog?

Tags: image, modal-dialog, tagging

I am developing a bookmarking service allowing users to save an image into a specific folder.

Users can replace the original photo with a custom one from different sources (PC, Webcam, URL)

Once the image is uploaded users can also add tags to the image.

I have the feeling that this dialog is becoming too long and since it expands vertically I am alfraid that may be hard to fill in for small resolution screens.

How can I improve the usability of this dialog?

Comment: You can resize de modal and the image within it to fill the viewport size. Facebook image viewing modal is a good example.

Comment: A screenshot or wireframe is very helpful on these types of questions. We don't really know what it looks like in the first place. :)

Answer (score 1):

Except your fear of height, height of some hundreds pixels (: , I yet don't see a problem as that. Or I dunno understand that is required.

[image: smth like that]

I hope that you will be a lucky guy who the first will see the user of accurately filling 50 and more tags per image, except for those who tries to enter all nonsense to a tagline at photostock websites. (:

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps don't show a dialog of all options. Give them a form text field and after the first letter is typed, start showing the results in a dropdown -or something. The more letters, the less results of come back.